# How to design Crystal report with Dynamic Data

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports-2008

Good Afternoon Developers,
This is my function to generate the crystal Report,This will take the Report Name and ReportQuery as a input parameter and will generate a dataset , With this dataset how can i design my Report??Because this is Generated at the runtime , How can i access that to generate my ReportDesign??

```
public void fnLoadDataToReport(string rptName, string rptQuery)
{
    try
    {
        DataSet myDS=new DataSet();
//      crReportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("Reports\" & RptName), OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByTempCopy);
        crReportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("Reports\\" + rptName ));
        SqlConnection myConnection=new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycon"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand myCommand=new SqlCommand(rptQuery,myConnection);
        SqlDataAdapter MyDA=new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
        MyDA.Fill(myDS,"ReportTable");
        crReportDocument.SetDataSource(myDS);
        crvReportGeneration.ReportSource=crReportDocument;
        crvReportGeneration.ShowFirstPage();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciable....!

Comment: Try to encapsulate the SqlConnection, SqlCommand and SqlDataAdapter with a using statement - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: Whats the use of encapsulating? And what to do after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is an **XML schema definition** of the **Dataset** to be able to design the report. this can be achieved by the following code.

```
private void WriteSchemaToFile(DataSet thisDataSet){
   // Set the file path and name. Modify this for your purposes.
   string filename="mySchema.xml";
   // Write the schema to the file.
   thisDataSet.WriteXmlSchema(filename);
}
```

now add the above created file to your project.

Now while designing the report select **Database expert** and select the xml file under **Project**. and add it (just like you add tables or views).

Now you are good to go. The rest of the steps are same.

Just make sure the name of the XSD schema and the table name in your Dataset match exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Why are using DataSet as the source for the report. Instead of that if you use a stored procedure as the source, it will solve your problem and also maintenance will be much more easier